# How to setup Signal Protocol in new/existing swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, signal-protocol

I've been searching for steps and a brief explanation regarding Signal Protocol integration in `Swift`.
I've gone through the [libsignal-protocol-java](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java) library, which can be used for `Android` Integration but haven't found a similar one for `iOS`.

Is there any way to integrate Signal Protocol library in an existing swift project?

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/blob/master/SignalServiceKit/README.md ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ? @ArunBalakrishnan

Comment: @AnkitKhanna No